# Magento 2 var/di folder is missing

Tags: magento2, command-line, di

There is no **di** folder generated in **var** directory. I am getting please re-run compile command. Why we need this **di** directory?

Answer (score 5):

If you have upgraded to Magento version 2.2.* then

```
var/generation has been moved to generated/code
```

and

```
var/di has been moved to generated/metadata
```

There shouldn't be var/di and var/generation folders after the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

**di** folder are generate at compile time inside var folder.

remove content of generation folder.
if **di** folder is not available first create **di** folder inside **var** folder.

Run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: what is the purpose & use of this di directory in magento?

Comment: when in developer mode, is it normal I got a 'generated' folder in the root after running that command?

Answer (score 0):

di folder is generated by magento itself. Each time you run:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Magento will generate the files

Comment: Yes but when I try to execute this command, I am getting error

Comment: What is that error?

Comment: 1. var/generation folder is not empty  2.class Cli not found.

Comment: If i try to delete generation folder ,it automatically regenerates instantly.

Comment: you might need to clear the cache using: sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* and give the ownership to Magento file system owner.

Comment: what is the use of this di directory in magento?

Comment: di stands for Dependency Injection

Comment: purpose? I mean when should I execute this command? When will it be required?

Comment: Whenever you change somewhere in the code that deals with dependency injection such as objectManager

Answer (score 0):

Magento itself creates the directory, `var/di`.

Missing of this directory (may be due to permission issue) causes

> please re-run compile command

message during running of

`setup:upgrade command`.

I also faced same issue. Then I manually created 'di' directory inside 'var' directory and set proper permission. It solved this issue for me. Then after I didn't get any such message.